# Heroku - Spring Boot App - Process exited with status 1

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

trying to run a 'hello world' Spring Boot App (that runs ok locally) I got this message:

```
2018-10-20T06:32:21.827918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-10-20T06:32:24.676953+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=35016 $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/das-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
2018-10-20T06:32:27.138742+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-10-20T06:32:27.142496+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2018-10-20T06:32:27.266974+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in target/das-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2018-10-20T06:32:27.324779+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-20T06:32:27.343816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

You can find the code on github for more details (https://github.com/ricgonmen/das-boot).

I have try to run it with and without Procfile but nothing change. I don't know how to get more information about the crash to solve it. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: From Review: Please add the code of your app by EDITING your question (do not post it as a comment to your own question). Thanks

Comment: Can you please show your main class

Comment: Thanks for your coments, sorry I dind't add it before. You can find the code on github as edited on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be your issue: `no main manifest attribute, in target/das-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Can you try by adding this to the plugins section of your `pom.xml` ?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

More information can be found here: [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-include-maven-plugin)